# I have 5 functions I want to print 5 functions output on same line when i call these functions, please tell how to do it. If i call these functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def one():
    print("1")

def two():
    print("2")


def three():
    print("3")

def four():
    print("4")

def five():
    print("5")

print(one(),two(),three(),four(),five(),end="")
```

Comment: The functions should return a value, not print it.

Comment: Alternatively to @Barmar comment. You just can invoke these functions, not print them

Comment: @OscarMartinez No, that won't print the results all on the same line.

Comment: True, in that case he should add `end=""` to each print call inside each function

Answer (score -1):

Would this work?

```
def one(): return("1")

def two(): return("2")

def three(): return("3")

def four(): return("4")

def five(): return("5")

print(one(),two(),three(),four(),five(),end="")
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: Don't just post code, explain the problem and how you fixed it.

Comment: Yes it's perfectly works did you explain how print and return work in this program

Answer (score -1):

```
def one(): return "1"

def two(): return "2"

def three(): return "3"

def four(): return "4"

def five(): return "5"

print(one(),two(),three(),four(),five(),end="")
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain the problem and how you fixed it.

Comment: Yes it's perfectly works did you explain how print and return work in this program